# How to know the response data type of API using requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have one simple question, is there a easy way to know the type of API's response?

Fox example:

Using `requests` post method to send api requests, some apis will return data format as .xml type or .json type,

how can i know the response type so i can choose not to convert to .json use `json()` when response type is .xml?

Comment: You can look at the `Content-Type` header on the response, that tells you what the body represents.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't know call which method to get the reponse Content-Type

Comment: Then see https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-headers

Comment: Thanks a lot , that help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `r.headers.get('content-type')` to get the response type